# How can I make this java code go back to a certain point in the code?

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, calculator

So as you could probably tell, it is a calculator. This is the second program I have made in Java, besides robotics code. I am pretty new to Java, so I don't know a ton about it. I want to be able to go back to the menu (lines 19-27) after it gives the answer to the question. If I can do this, I will put something like M for menu or E to exit after the answer. I want it so if they put M, it will go back to those lines of code to be able to start over again instead of restarting the program. Thanks, Matt.

```
public class Calculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Calculator");
    System.out.println("----------");
    System.out.println("Press 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for subtraction");
    System.out.println("Press 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Press 4 for division");
    int Menu;
    Scanner menu_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Menu = menu_scanner.nextInt();
    if (Menu == 1){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number in the problem");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        double iAddition1;
        double iAddition2;
        double aAddition;
        Scanner sAddition1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        iAddition1 = sAddition1.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number in the problem");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        Scanner sAddition2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        iAddition2 = sAddition2.nextDouble();
        aAddition = iAddition1 + iAddition2;
        System.out.println("The answer to " + iAddition1 + " + " + iAddition2 + " = " + aAddition);
    }
    if (Menu == 2){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number in the problem");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        double iSubtraction1;
        Scanner sSubtraction1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        iSubtraction1 = sSubtraction1.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number in the problem");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        double iSubtraction2;
        Scanner sSubtraction2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        iSubtraction2 = sSubtraction2.nextDouble();
        double aSubtraction = iSubtraction1 - iSubtraction2;
        System.out.println("The answer to " + iSubtraction1 + " - " + iSubtraction2 + " = " + aSubtraction);
    }
    if (Menu == 3){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number in the problem");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        double iMultiplication1;
        double iMultiplication2;
        Scanner sMultiplication1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        iMultiplication1 = sMultiplication1.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number in the problem");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        Scanner sMultiplication2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        iMultiplication2 = sMultiplication2.nextDouble();
        double aMultiplication = iMultiplication1 * iMultiplication2;
        System.out.println("The answer to " + iMultiplication1 + " * " + iMultiplication2 + " = " + aMultiplication);
    }
    if (Menu == 4){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number in the problem");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        Scanner sDivision1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        double iDivision1;
        iDivision1 = sDivision1.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number in the problem");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        Scanner sDivision2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        double iDivision2;
        iDivision2 = sDivision1.nextDouble();
        double aDivision = iDivision1 / iDivision2;
        System.out.println("The answer to " + iDivision1 + " / " + iDivision2 + " = " + aDivision);
    }
}    
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about functions.

Comment: @SLaks - The guy needs to learn about everything.

Comment: See what happens you do `System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");`

Comment: I feel sorry for the robot. I suggest reading the Java tutorials on Oracle's website, start at the beginning.

Comment: by the way, i have only programmed java for about 1 month and only am learning 2 hours a week from a robotics mentor, so sorry i dont know everything about java.

Comment: Does this "mentor" actually read your code, or is he more of a spirit guide?

Comment: Well at first, he watched me code and helped me, now I code myself and show him before I deploy the code and test it.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a loop. Probably a while loop.

Answer (score 5):

A `while` loop with a condition of your choice (such as checking a certain value isn't encountered), or a `for` loop with a certain number of iterations if you're content with doing the set of operations, say, 10 times for example.

One solution is to wrap the entire block of code after `Menu = menu_scanner.nextInt` in a `while` loop such as `while(Menu < 5)`, and offer another option of 5 to exit the program.

Essentially though, you need to learn about the control structures in Java from a guide e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Answer (score 2):

First off all try to group parts of your program into functions. You can do a loops with a [`while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) or [`for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop. You can do this also with [labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you reduce the amount of code you have by using method. I also think you should  use cases for e.g

```
public static double doMath(double firstNum,double secondNum){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner();  
    System.out.println("Enter the operation number?"); 
    int i = scan.nextInt(); 

    switch (i) {
        case 1: total = firstnum + secondNum; 
        break;
        case 2: total = firstnum - secondNum; 
        break;
        ......
    }

    return total; 
}
```

This method take two numbers (**doMath**(*first*, *second*)) and return the total/answer.

It's a very good start but every time you see yourself repeating lines of code take advantage   of methods/functions they are very important in programming. Also use while loops to repeat the call until the user wants to end the program.

**Wish you the best of luck**

Answer (score -2):

I am also new to Java programing, but i agree a **"While Loop"** is what you need.

***My Version of your Code:***

***http://pastebin.com/H34FRWP3***

**Good Luck :)**

*I use Eclipse IDE, it has helped me* **ALOT**.

http://eclipse.org

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).